# JQuery navbar hidden behind JQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

I have a JQuery dropdown which is hiding behind a JQuery slideshow directly under it, [here](http://www.andb.x10.mx/aaa-home.html).

I need to get the dropdown on top...I have tried z-index to no effect.

From what I can see from doing research this is a fairly common issue...can anyone help?

Code:

```
#nav {
width:800px;
margin:0px auto 0px;
height:25px;
}

#nav ul {
height:25px;
margin:0 0px 0 0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

#nav ul li {
background:#76bf43;
padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
margin:0 10px 0 0;
color:#ffffff;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
width:100px;
text-align:center;
height:20px;
float:left;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
cursor:pointer;
}

#nav ul li ul {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#nav ul li ul li {
padding:0;
margin:0;
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
height:25px;
}



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aaa-styles.css" />

<script src="jq.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.timer.js"></script>
<script src="image-rotator.js"></script>



<script src="hoverIntent.js"></script> 
<script src="superfish.js"></script> 


<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("ul.sf-menu").superfish(); 
}); 

</script>


</head>



<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//This keeps track of the slideshow's current location
var current_panel = 1;
//Controlling the duration of animation by variable will simplify changes
var animation_duration = 2500;

$.timer(6000, function (timer) {
    //Determine the current location, and transition to next panel
    switch(current_panel){
        case 1:
            $("#slideshow").stop().animate({left: "-800px", top: "0px"}, {easing: 'easeOutBack', duration: animation_duration});
            current_panel = 2;
        break;
        case 2:
            $("#slideshow").stop().animate({left: "0px", top: "-210px"}, {easing: 'easeOutBack', duration: animation_duration});
            current_panel = 3;
        break;
        case 3:
            $("#slideshow").stop().animate({left: "-800px", top: "-210px"}, {easing: 'easeOutBack', duration: animation_duration});
            current_panel = 4;
        break;
        case 4:
            $("#slideshow").stop().animate({left: "0px", top: "0px"}, {easing: 'easeOutBack', duration: animation_duration});
            current_panel = 1;
        break;
        timer.reset(12000);
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Use something like the developer mode in Chrome or Safari to troubleshoot this. Using it you can see the exact styling that is applied to dynamically created elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess you were trying `z-index` on the wrong element. Give this a go.

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 40000;
}
```

You should find that will fix your issue.

Comment: I was z-ing the correct element, but I left out position:relative.  Thanks for jogging my memory!

Answer (score 0):

for `#nav ul` add `position:relative;z-index:1;`

`z-index` always applies to positioned elements as css documentation inform us.

Read more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index).